# Cakephp Render XML errors in custom Exception.renderer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

Based on the information here: [Using a custom renderer with Exception.renderer to handle application exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-a-custom-renderer-withexception-renderer-to-handle-application-exceptions)

I'm creating a custom error renderer that renders in XML format.

Below is the sample code for the render function in app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer:

```
public function render() {
    if (isset($this->controller->request->params['xml'])) {
        $this->controller->viewClass = "MyXml";
        $error = array(
            'app' => array(
                'error' => 'An unexpected error has occured.'
            )
        );
        $this->controller->set('error', $error);
        $this->controller->set('_serialize', 'error');
    }
}
```

However nothing gets returned. I have done some echo within the `if` condition and that shows.

So is it because the viewClass is not initialized while its in AppExceptionRenderer::render() stage?

There were no errors either.
"MyXml" viewClass works perfectly in normal controllers too.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I was missing the  render and send methods.
Here's the full working example.

```
<?php
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function __construct($exception) {
            parent::__construct($exception);
    }

    public function render() {

        // Handle errors
        if (isset($this->controller->request->params['xml'])) {
            Cakelog::error($this->error->getMessage());
            $this->controller->viewClass = "MyXml";
            $error = array(
                'app' => array(
                    'error' => 'An illegal operation has been detected.'
                )
            );
            $this->controller->set('error', $error);
            $this->controller->set('_serialize', 'error');
            $cakeResponseObject = $this->controller->render();
            $this->controller->response->send($cakeResponseObject);
        } else {
            if ($this->method) {
                call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->method), array($this->error));
            }
        }
    }
}
```